# How to root / update the fake Lenovo P780W

Tags: rooting, custom-roms

I tried searching for a guide to root the 'lenovo' P780 w model - but this model doesn't seem to appear in the various lists of devices which can be rooted (such as [Kingo](http://www.kingoapp.com/android-root/devices.htm) [Ready2Root](http://ready2root.com/all-devices) or the list in [this post](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/1185/52309)).

The closest information I could find regarding the P780w was at [xda-developer forums](http://forum.xda-developers.com/sitesearch.php?q=p780w) where [one of the links there](http://forum.xda-developers.com/lenovo-p780/development/lenovo-p780w-rom-flash-flash-tool-t2914263) had a download with a rom and flash tool, but on the other hand indicated that there was no development for this type of phone, and that the rom was only for already broken phones.

I'm guessing that this is because the phone is a [fake](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Cwbdc3M4DbI).

So my question is basically:

1) How can I safely root this fake phone and

2) [If it is actually possible to root this phone]: Is there a custom ROM for this phone so that I can update the operating system and Android version from 4.2.2 jellybean to 4.4 or higher?

I'm especially interested in advice from users which also acquired this phone and successfully rooted / updated it with a custom ROM.

PS: I'm sure it's the fake phone that I have. I purchased it via ali express China.

Also, if there are any necessary details about the phone which I haven't mentioned - please let me know and I will post them.

Comment: Well, we surely don't know if your phone is fake Lenovo or not, but the assumption that it's fake because it's not listed on [that post](http://android.stackexchange.com/a/1185/52309) is actually wrong (the title is "How do I root x?", not "Can I root x?"). It's because we haven't encountered this question before. Before I'm adding the entry there, could you confirm if your phone is [Lenovo P780](http://www.gsmarena.com/lenovo_p780-5544.php)... or the fake P780W?

Comment: @AndrewT.  It's definitely the fake Lenovo p780w. That's also what appears in the 'about phone' in the settings. Also I edited the post - hope it's a bit more clear

Answer (score 1):

Most Chinese fake phones can easily be rooted as they do not carry any bloatware, skins, extra bundles etc. These phones contain a near stock version of android and thus, don't cause any problems (usually) while rooting. You should be able to use cyanogenmod, it usually works very well on Chinese phones.

Best of luck.
Rahul.

PS: To be on the safe side, remember to take a backup.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for this answer, it seems like you have experience with these phones. Could you elaborate a bit about how I should go about rooting the phone. eg Which program you have used and which model phone I should choose (from the list of models) in order to root my P780w

Comment: You can use one-click-root. It usually works. You can select a similar lenovo phone. You can also download rooting apps from http://uptodown.com

Comment: +1 Thanks. In your experience, if the root fails - will this 'break' /' brick' the phone or will I be able to restore the phone to the way it was before the root attempt. Also could you recommend a backup tool. Thanks

Comment: Also, [oneclickroot](http://www.oneclickroot.com/) seems to be dead now. Any other software which worked for you?

Comment: Rooting apps don't brick your phone, they just tell you if it isn't supported. Otherwise, recovering a bricked phone is often impossible

Comment: Thanks for your help, but in order to award the bounty I'm looking for something a little more concrete like: Use software 'x' and choose modal 'y' - 'that's what worked for me so it will most likely also work for you'....  or something like that

Comment: Then in that case, use Z4 Root, Towelroot, Kingo, SRS Root or UnlockRoot. All of them worked for me!

Comment: Well OK, here you go. But let's say I use Kingo. Which model phone should I choose? There's no p780w in the list

Comment: You'll gave to do some research and select a model which has similar specs to your phone for example, your phone has a 6mp camera, 480p display, 6gb storage and 1gb ram, and there is a phone x, which has a 8mp camera, 480p display, 2gb of ram, and 8gb storage, then both devices are similar so kingo should work, also see the android version both phones come shipped with. Be sure to ask any questions or queries.