# How to increase wireless speed supported by Android TV BOX CS928?

Tags: wi-fi, data-transfer, android-tv

i have recently purchased **Android Tv Box CS928** from Chinese site http://www.aliexpress.com/item/CS928-Android-4-4-kitkat-Rk3288-A17-quad-core-2GB-16GB-2-4-5-0Ghz-100M/1939723909.html

i bought this because it says

```
Network     2.4GHz/5GHz WiFi 802.11 b/g/n and 802.11 a/c. Support LAN 100M/1000M Base-T
```

so i was under impression that (802.11 n and 802.11 a/c means 300 Mbps) this will be perfect fit for my home wireless network which is working at **300 Mbps** using wireless router **TP-Link 1043ND**

but when i connected my Android Tv Box CS928 to wireless network in my home i can only get 65 Mbps highest speed at the Android Tv Box CS928 , i even tried placing the my TP-Link router next to Android TV box but it didn't increase the Wireless speed , it shows signal strength as 100% but the wireless speed is **65 Mbps**.

So i have tried forcing my TP-LINK wireless router to transmit and work at only at 300 Mbps speed by setting

```
Channel:    1
Mode:   11n only
Channel Width:  40MHz
Max Tx Rate:    300Mbps
```

but still the Android TV BOX connection status shows wireless speed as **65 Mbps**

why is that ?

how can i increase the wireless transfer speed of Android TV box so i can watch HD movies streamed from my PC to Android TV Box?

Comment: [This answer on Super User](http://superuser.com/a/359378/356789) might be related.

Comment: @AndrewT. Thanks for the link, if thats the case then i feel cheated too and its too late.

Comment: I'm still not sure though, hopefully it's just only a misconfiguration (but I'm not an expert at networking). On the other hand, might be careful when shopping from there again (the other case, [fake Lenovo P780 w](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/95981/how-to-root-update-the-fake-lenovo-p780w))